# Representing a sector mathematically

Tags: geometry, circles

Just like we represent, say a circle in terms of its radius either in a cartesian or polar system, in a similar manner, can we represent a sector of the circle mathematically? I want the solution to build a model for which I need a clear representation of the sector, mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sector of the circle with radius $R$ centered at $(0,0)$ is$$\left\{\bigl(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)\bigr)\,\middle|\,0\leqslant r\leqslant R\text{ and }\theta_0\leqslant\theta\leqslant\theta_1\right\}$$for two numbers $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ such that $\theta_0\leqslant\theta_1$.

Comment: Can you please explain as to what is r and two numbers and also if (0,0) is not the origin, how will the equation change? If am not wrong, I guess theta is the central angle of the sector?

Comment: @shivangi120693 If you want the center to be $(x,y)$, just add $x$ to the first coordinate and $y$ to the second one. The number $r$ is the distance to the center. The numbers $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are the angles that the rays that bound the circular sector make with the positive part of the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Are you trying to specify that 'r' is the radius, if not then the distance to the center is from where? Also, can you give some reference to this answer, so that I can read further to clarify my doubts?

Comment: @shivangi120693 The radius is $R$, not $r$. ANd I have no references since I did what I did by myself, not looking at a reference.

Comment: Sir, then again this distance to the center is from what point? Am sorry sir, I thought that may be it has some reference. Your insightful answer has really helped me, just stuck at the asked question.

Comment: @shivangi120693 If the center is $(x,y)$, $r$ is the distance form $(x+r\cos\theta,y+r\sin\theta)$ to $(x,y)$. If my answer was helpful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: In that case, if we have to calculate r and put it into the equation, how are we going to proceed on that?

Comment: @shivangi120693 I can't answer that. We *don't* have to calculate $r$.

Comment: Okay, thank you, sir.

Comment: Just a small query sir, what is the significance of taking r here? I mean can't we keep the equation with radius R?

Comment: @shivangi120693 Then what you will get will be an arc, not a circular sector.